# Convert a boxed integer to an nullable integer with potentially different type

Tags: c#, generics, integer, casting

Given a boxed integer (with a boxed `short`, `int`, ...) I want to convert it to an unboxed, nullable type instead. It should be possible to convert non-matching types (for example: boxed `int` to `short?`) Can you please comment on:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int? x = Unbox<int>((short)42);
        short? y = Unbox<short>(42);
    }

    static T? Unbox<T>(object x) where T : struct
    {
        return typeof(T) == x.GetType() ? (T)x : (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should probably add `IConvertible` restriction on `T`, since it is used by `Convert.ChangeType` method.

Also this check: `typeof(T) == x.GetType()` looks like an overhead. `Convert.ChangeType` does nothing if types match. For example, check out `Int32` [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs):

```
int IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) {
    return m_value;
}
```

So you might as well just check for `null` instead:

```
static T? Unbox<T>(object x) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (x == null) return null;
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T));
}
```

**Edit:** as mentioned by sir *t3chb0t*, there are cases, where `Convert.ChangeType` can throw. So it *might* be a good idea to swallow exceptions inside your method and return `null` in those cases. But it also can be a very bad idea. It depends on use case, which you should carefully evaluate.

Comment: Note though, that `ChangeType` could have taken an `IConvertible` but chose to take `object` instead. It does support non-`IConvertible` "conversions". (See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847997/why-does-convert-changetype-take-an-object-parameter)

Comment: should just make it `return x == null ? null : (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T));`  one line it, or maybe better `return x != null ? (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T)) : null;`

Comment: @user127866 great observation. So if types match, `ChangeType` does not even hit actual `IConvertible` implementation. That's pretty weird design choice on Microsoft's part.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure if you understand what boxing means because you use an `int` in the example.

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type `object` or to any interface type implemented by this value type.

and

> When the CLR boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object and stores it on the managed heap.

and

> Unboxing extracts the value type from the object.

This would be unboxing. First box the `int` as `object` and then unbox it again.

```
object value = (short)42;
int? x = (int?)(short)value;
short? y = (short?)value;
```

---

I find this method is unecessary. You're better off with *normal* casting then with this and its overhead.

The problem with `ChangeType` is that

> The `ChangeType(Object, Type)` method can convert a nullable type to another type. However, **it cannot convert another type to a value of a nullable type**, even if conversionType is the underlying type of the Nullable.To perform the conversion, you can use a casting operator (in C#) or a conversion function (in Visual Basic). The following example illustrates the conversion to and from a nullable type.

So this won't work:

```
short? z = (short?)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(short?));
```

but you

> want to convert it to an unboxed, nullable type instead.

this means that if you still want to use the `Unbox` method the *correct* version of it should able to actually accept the `int?` as a parameter and return the `default(T)` rather then a `null`:

```
static T Unbox<T>(object x)
{
    if (x == null) return default(T);
    var nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, nullableType ?? typeof(T));
}
```

but this is still casting the result with `(T)` so we're back at the beginning... this method is unnecessary.

---

Oh, and there is one more thing. `ChangeType` will blow if you try to convert `int` to `short` that exceedes the `short`.

It'll also hide the fact that you can loose precision when converting incompatibile types.

Consider this:

```
object value = (double)12.3;

short x = (short)(double)value;
int y = Unbox<int>(value);
```

To get the `x` you need to explicitly and deliberately cast it to `short` and see and know that you are converting `double` and may loose precision.

Getting the `y` via `Unbox` silently removes the fractional part.

Comment: While your statements are true, I am sorry that I failed in making the question more clear. a) Unboxed takes `objects`, "you use an `int`" is not correct/missunderstanding. b1) I did not intend that ConvertType would handle null, this was a bug in my question (which the rules of this site prevented me to edit) Sorry. I just use a null check to handle nulls now. b2) Normal casting requires multiple methods. In this case I don't want normal casting because I don't know the type to cast to. A generic method is what I want. c) I should have said, that I am not concerned with overflows. I am sorry.

Comment: @user127866 thx for clarifying - next time you'll give more details and there won't by any misunderstandings ;-)

Comment: @user127866 out of curiosity, why don't you know the data type?

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want to *unbox* the value and not simply convert it you can use the [Expression API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) to build a function that does exactly that, in pseudo-code:

```
Func<object, TResult> = boxedValue => (TResult)(typeof(boxedValue))boxedValue;
```

To build the function you'll need a helper class to construct the delegate with the correct types:

```
static class UnboxerCache<TResult>
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object, TResult>> UnboxerLookup = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object, TResult>>();

    public static Func<object, TResult> GetUnboxer(Type actualType)
    {
        return UnboxerLookup.GetOrAdd(actualType, CreateUnboxer);
    }

    private static Func<object, TResult> CreateUnboxer(Type actualType)
    {
        var boxedParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "boxedValue");
        var unboxedValue = Expression.Unbox(boxedParameter, actualType);
        var convertedValue = Expression.Convert(unboxedValue, typeof(TResult));

        var unboxer = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, TResult>>(convertedValue, boxedParameter);

        return unboxer.Compile();
    }
}
```

Here we have a mapping from the actual type of the object to a delegate that can unbox and cast it to the result type. The construction of the delegate is pretty simple, convert the `boxedValue` to the actual type and then to the result type.

I would make the actual unboxer a separate class with that sole resposibility:

```
public static class Unbox
{
    public static TResult? To<TResult>(object boxedValue)
        where TResult : struct
    {
        if (boxedValue == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var actualType = boxedValue.GetType();
        var resultType = typeof(TResult);
        if (actualType == resultType)
        {
            return (TResult)boxedValue;
        }

        var unboxer = UnboxerCache<TResult>.GetUnboxer(actualType);
        return unboxer(boxedValue);
    }

    private static class UnboxerCache<TResult>
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object, TResult>> UnboxerLookup = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object, TResult>>();

        public static Func<object, TResult> GetUnboxer(Type actualType)
        {
            return UnboxerLookup.GetOrAdd(actualType, CreateUnboxer);
        }

        private static Func<object, TResult> CreateUnboxer(Type actualType)
        {
            var boxedParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "boxedValue");
            var unboxedValue = Expression.Unbox(boxedParameter, actualType);
            var convertedValue = Expression.Convert(unboxedValue, typeof(TResult));

            var unboxer = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, TResult>>(convertedValue, boxedParameter);

            return unboxer.Compile();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally you should consider verifying that the type of the boxed value is a value type (`boxedValue.GetType().IsValueType`) and maybe raise an error if that isn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

`Unbox<T>` is missing a `null` check. The call `x.GetType()` will fail if `x = null`.

```
static T? Unbox<T>(object x) where T : struct
{
    if (x == null)
        return null;

    return typeof(T) == x.GetType() ? (T)x : (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to work well:

```
if (valueType == typeof(int))
   field.Value =(int) Convert.ChangeType(reader.Value, valueType);
else 
   field.Value = (dynamic)Convert.ChangeType(reader.Value, valueType);
```

you have to be explicit with `int`, but all other primitive types work fine for me.